# How to explicitly show this equality involving wedge and tensor?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tensor-products, complex-geometry, exterior-algebra

Suppose $X$ is a complex manifold, $\alpha\in\mathcal A^{0,p}(T^{1,0}_X), \beta\in\mathcal A^{0,q}(T^{1,0}_X).$ Then locally, $\alpha=ad\bar z_I\otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i},\beta=bd\bar z_J\otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j},$ where $|I|=p, |J|=q$. Then, I want to show $$\alpha\wedge\beta={(-1)}^q(d\bar z_I\wedge d\bar z_J)\otimes(a\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}\wedge b\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j}),$$
i.e.,  $(d\bar z_I\otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i})\wedge (d\bar z_J\otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j})={(-1)}^q(d\bar z_I\wedge d\bar z_J)\otimes(\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}\wedge \frac{\partial}{\partial z_j}).$

I know $dz_1\wedge dz_2=-dz_2\wedge dz_1$, however, I feel confused when dealing with wedge about tangent vector and differential.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your definition of $\wedge$ here? I am a bit unsure since what these are $T^{1,0}_X$-valued forms. What is the action on $T^{1,0}_X$?

Comment: It might be useful to note that the wedge product $\wedge$ is defined by $v \wedge w : = (v \otimes w)/\sim$, where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation defined by $x \otimes x \sim 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: The usual setting in which this is defined is with Lie algebra-valued differential forms, and then one uses the Lie bracket to get the wedge product as again a Lie algebra-valued differential form. Since vector fields (smooth or holomorphic, in this case) form a Lie algebra, perhaps that's what's intended. In all my years working in complex geometry, I don't think I ever encountered what you're suggesting.

Comment: @TedShifrin, this problem comes from <<Complex Geometry>> written by Daniel Huybrechts, the proof of Tian-Todorov lemma (page 263, line 10, one indeed computes... the second inequality), where $(-1)^q$ appears.